# How to create a build job for a simple java project

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am very new to Jenkins. I have gone throught the tutorial of jenkins and I want to create a build job for simple java project. I know how to create a freestylebuild but I dont see any connection between the build and the project. Whats happening exactly. I have my project in eclipse and how can i create a build to the project. How do i know that it is the exact build for this project. 
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best thing to do would be to move your build to some standard command line tool, like [ant](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin), [maven](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+2+Project+Plugin), [ivy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ivy+Plugin), [gradle](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) etc and then you can reuse the same build from your IDE and on jenkins. note that this doesnt mean giving up using your IDE - many IDEs can import these types of projects directly and give you all the benefits youre used to in an IDE. it simply means that you get a build thats "portable" and not tied down to the specific IDE your using.

personally i think maven is best supported in this regard, but its mostly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. For example I have java project MyNewClass and I want to create a build for it. How do I create a build for it using Jenkins. (I want to create a freestylebuild using jenkins but then while I am creating this build I dont see anywhere mentioning the project name. So how is it possible to say that this is the build for the particular project)

Comment: @user1983063 - i've never done a freestyle jenkins build so i dont know, but if you follow this short guide you could probbaly make your project into a maven build in no time: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with this problem as well. While creating build job where should I specify my project in the build ??

Comment: @user1983063 - what do you mean? you just tell it where your pom.xml is

Comment: I mean I have my project in Eclipse. I want to create a build job for my project which resides in Eclipse workspace. When I am creating a build job in Jenkins how do I specify that for this project I am going to create a build job. Hope you understand my question..

Comment: @user1983063 - you misunderstood. jenkins cannot build eclipse projects, it cannot read and understand eclipse project files. make your project into a maven project so you could build it using maven from the command line. then both jenkins and eclipse can use the maven build.

Comment: Yeah. I was wrong. I have created a normal Java project and trying to invoke in Jenkins. My stupid and unawareness. Now I have created a Maven project and compiled, packaged and executed the build using command prompt. Later check out and commit the project folder through subversion and finally created a new buildjob in jenkins . In the subversion field I have given the path of the project(commited). Now my first build is SUCCESS. Thank you once again.

Comment: My requirement is also same, only thing is i want to perform the action of building a project only when code is being commited in SVN. Can you please guide me ? user1983063